# Cannot play local mp3 file using MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working with MediaPlayer on Android to play mp3. When I play mp3 file from network using url , it is working fine. But when I play local mp3 file in Download folder, it is not playing. It is not showing error as well.

This is how I play local file

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("Download/9591455192457575.mp3"));
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

I already checked, the file really exists. I run it in "try catch" statement and error message in catch block is empty. What is wrong with my code, and how can I play local file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you cant access download directory like that. You need to get Download library like this.

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

(available since API 8) To access individual files in this directory use either File.list() or File.listFiles().

Try like this

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/9591455192457575.mp3"));
```

**NOTE**

you need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Yes . I will cause it has time limitation. :)